# Page vertical scroll

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a question about vertical scrolling. I dont have any code to show but I have a picture of Chrome setting page:

[image]

My question is: how exactly was it done that the vertical scroll bar goes all away to the top, but it does not scroll the whole page - History is not moving when we scroll. I looked into the source code and look kind of scary with all these iframes and links to Chrome. I even dont know if it's ok to include these links into a commercial product. I am trying to mimic that kind on behavior in Bootstrap world, but cannot get even close to something like this. Any hint which direction to go?

Thanks

Added this simplified code after suggestions:

```
div style="overflow:auto;z-index:99999;position:fixed">
<div class="container-fluid" style="min-width:1200px;display:inline-block;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

But I am not getting any scrolling.

Comment: Check if my answer suits you?

Comment: Will try it later and update your answer as appropriate.

Comment: Sure, please don't forget.

Comment: What if I cannot have an outer div (that scrolls) and inner div ( that gets scrolled) next to each other? What I am saying is that I want it look like I am scrolling the browser window but the area inside is actually scrolling.

Comment: Mark, this is how BootStrap and other places have implemented... You can't have the other way, as it is really buggy.

Comment: I added some code

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

> How exactly was it done that the vertical scroll bar goes all away to the top, but it does not scroll the whole page - History is not moving when we scroll.

By using `position: fixed`. It stays in the same place.

> I looked into the source code and look kind of scary with all these iFrames and links to Chrome. I even don't know if it's ok to include these links into a commercial product.

No! Never use iFrames in any of the new products. They are still available for just embedding purposes only, that too for cross domain embeds.

> I am trying to mimic that kind on behaviour in Bootstrap world, but cannot get even close to something like this. Any hint which direction to go?

Bootstrap already has it in its modal windows. Like for eg., you can recreate them by the following steps:

1. Give `body` the `overflow: hidden`.
2. Make a `div` with `position: fixed` and a big `z-index` taking the whole mask.
3. Make sure you give `overflow: auto` to this mask `div`.
4. Inside that `div`, add a little `div` that holds the real window.
5. If the smaller window `div` overflows, the scroll bars appear on the main `div`, which looks like it appears on the `body`, while `body` scroll is unaffected.

A sample snippet would be:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("open-mask").onclick = function() {
    document.body.classList.add('mask-on');
    document.getElementsByClassName("mask")[0].classList.remove('hidden');
    return false;
  };
};
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.mask {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99998;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 150px 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.mask .window {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}
.mask-on {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="mask hidden">
  <div class="window">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi nemo quos sed, similique fugiat autem? Facere ex hic mollitia, dolore quasi dolor laudantium asperiores! Esse perferendis ratione, porro sequi deserunt.</p>
    <p>Numquam blanditiis obcaecati, quae reiciendis sint consequuntur eaque illo dolorem distinctio animi esse excepturi accusantium magni quam at repellendus expedita reprehenderit earum minima? Facere iusto ipsa quod repudiandae deserunt quibusdam.</p>
    <p>Sint rerum natus asperiores earum atque dolor voluptatem perferendis excepturi, repellat nemo sequi neque, vel architecto provident deserunt commodi soluta quis voluptatum vitae iure. Aliquid, nihil, iste. A ab, itaque.</p>
    <p>Iste itaque quia corporis dolorem est, voluptas, sunt magni cum neque reiciendis, veritatis incidunt esse ratione consectetur exercitationem, cupiditate officia ab repellat maiores illo voluptatibus et ad accusamus. Error, excepturi.</p>
    <p>Tempora non, dolorem unde suscipit voluptatum velit eligendi placeat cumque corporis neque labore quae, id temporibus? Qui quidem a error rem, molestias esse sit dolore asperiores expedita nisi omnis animi?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi nemo quos sed, similique fugiat autem? Facere ex hic mollitia, dolore quasi dolor laudantium asperiores! Esse perferendis ratione, porro sequi deserunt.</p>
    <p>Numquam blanditiis obcaecati, quae reiciendis sint consequuntur eaque illo dolorem distinctio animi esse excepturi accusantium magni quam at repellendus expedita reprehenderit earum minima? Facere iusto ipsa quod repudiandae deserunt quibusdam.</p>
    <p>Sint rerum natus asperiores earum atque dolor voluptatem perferendis excepturi, repellat nemo sequi neque, vel architecto provident deserunt commodi soluta quis voluptatum vitae iure. Aliquid, nihil, iste. A ab, itaque.</p>
    <p>Iste itaque quia corporis dolorem est, voluptas, sunt magni cum neque reiciendis, veritatis incidunt esse ratione consectetur exercitationem, cupiditate officia ab repellat maiores illo voluptatibus et ad accusamus. Error, excepturi.</p>
    <p>Tempora non, dolorem unde suscipit voluptatum velit eligendi placeat cumque corporis neque labore quae, id temporibus? Qui quidem a error rem, molestias esse sit dolore asperiores expedita nisi omnis animi?</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  <a href="javascript:;" id="open-mask">Open Mask</a>
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis doloremque veritatis ipsam! Odit id a consectetur earum molestias, reiciendis quam ad molestiae maxime impedit magni blanditiis, omnis sunt neque nihil.</p>
<p>Similique iure vitae, qui nostrum necessitatibus modi sequi odio nobis, eius molestias placeat, quos debitis? Aspernatur deserunt doloribus laboriosam illo pariatur asperiores quo officia iusto accusantium, saepe, provident qui facilis!</p>
<p>Ducimus, repudiandae dolores. Error animi vitae dolore, aliquam eius eos quidem veritatis debitis blanditiis. Dignissimos, commodi consequuntur. Et, inventore nulla quae, ad maxime animi iste. Voluptas nihil mollitia tempore unde!</p>
<p>Cumque qui expedita perspiciatis quia sunt suscipit adipisci! Architecto nesciunt exercitationem alias esse earum iste beatae nihil id obcaecati adipisci quaerat accusamus eaque blanditiis, mollitia, placeat modi, deserunt perferendis maxime.</p>
<p>Magnam veritatis perspiciatis ex optio consequatur dolore culpa, nostrum quibusdam illo inventore fugiat explicabo unde magni, voluptatem asperiores laboriosam commodi impedit nemo molestiae. Libero dolores modi magnam fugit. Autem, cum.</p>
<p>Sit voluptatibus quasi, voluptatem tempora culpa sed esse animi ut quas eligendi quos sequi amet, molestiae officia nulla laboriosam dolorem ipsum vel earum laudantium! Nihil blanditiis, a esse incidunt molestiae.</p>
<p>Aut recusandae at fugit ad officia fuga odio, dolorem vitae, natus neque laborum porro provident illum accusamus inventore vel tempora similique maxime soluta ab culpa. Sit consequuntur consectetur accusantium distinctio.</p>
<p>Doloribus dignissimos praesentium, tempore, distinctio perspiciatis quas enim repellat eos eius omnis ratione blanditiis unde dolorum, mollitia. Doloremque, nisi amet, tenetur libero dolorem quis natus ducimus vitae, eveniet ratione commodi.</p>
<p>Alias, facilis, sit. Dolorem, blanditiis. Qui vel modi sunt, architecto optio saepe quo culpa. Atque iste velit unde assumenda quasi, amet nesciunt vitae id quo, eum eveniet ducimus. A, libero.</p>
<p>Id expedita, quas, tempore est vitae aspernatur sit sequi odio necessitatibus omnis totam nihil unde nulla eaque tempora, voluptate? Inventore soluta, consectetur animi sit alias ab veniam qui officia incidunt.</p>
<p>Placeat quas, maiores accusamus odio laudantium. Possimus accusamus beatae, architecto porro. Sunt in neque, atque, minima odio pariatur maiores, consectetur dolorem recusandae rem, eveniet possimus aut repudiandae numquam ad saepe!</p>
<p>Rem officiis molestiae ipsam veritatis soluta in assumenda culpa voluptatibus quo modi necessitatibus beatae mollitia officia deleniti ullam neque, qui, porro nesciunt maxime! Veritatis aut aliquam sunt impedit repudiandae iusto.</p>
<p>Autem labore quod magnam. Enim ad dolorem, reprehenderit repellendus architecto, officia quis nihil quia laudantium totam nisi velit neque voluptatibus saepe cum in unde consectetur quidem non omnis, consequatur praesentium.</p>
<p>Cupiditate ipsam, animi esse exercitationem, neque tempora eum aperiam. Illum adipisci minima necessitatibus quae, laudantium assumenda suscipit, quas, natus corporis temporibus voluptatum officiis molestias obcaecati culpa provident nisi maxime possimus!</p>
<p>Voluptatibus cumque eius illum esse laudantium tempora consequuntur unde harum, voluptates dolor ex quidem, tenetur, enim culpa ullam similique dolorum corporis nam voluptas voluptatum. Aperiam nam saepe earum sequi laudantium.</p>
```

**Note:** You need to rerun the code snippet to close the modal popup.